# Créating a private user space (with login and pswd) with Node.js and Postgresql

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, authentication

I'm a beginner developer (but I try to improve myself ;) ) and I develop a website with a public section and a "private" one requiring a connection!
My site is developed in HTML , CSS and Javascript and I use Bootstrap for different effects (including a popup to connect) and my user-database is on Postgresql.

But now I have to manage all the connection system behind this popup that will enable the user to switch from the public site to the private one..and I really don't know how to do..for reasons of my own, I can not use php or java! So I started to turn to the Node.js solution, I do not know, but that seems to meet my needs!

I did some research and apparently I will need the following tools:
 - Node.js
 - Bower
 - PG package for Node.js
 - Express generator
 - Passport
 - and Grunt

I need your opinions and feedback on these tools and possibly some tips to put me on the path!

Thank you in advance for your help! : D

Answer (score 0):

Since you already established the tools that you need, you've already started.

What I use for my nodejs backend is Express, Passport and Sequelize. For the frontend I'm using angularjs.

For Sequelize tutorial - http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/1.7.0/articles/express/

For angularjs tutorial - http://tutorialzine.com/2013/08/learn-angularjs-5-examples/

You need to distinguish the public part of your site and the private part using both backend and frontend. In the backend you should do some authentication and do the same check on the frontend.

You could easily Google for these materials and you're up and running in no time.

Good luck.

Comment: Hey thx for your answer !
I'll look at Sequelize ! But what is the difference between angularjs and Express ! I though that Express was an app generator like Angular !?
And for the connection system with my postgres database, passport can get it ok ?

One more time : Thx for your fast answer !

Comment: Express to me is like jquery to javascript. It simplifies http requests. You can use Jade with express. Passport is for authorization.

Comment: oh ?! I though it was juste for front-end...
I read enough bad reviews on jade ...
I'm a bit lost with all these tools that I don't know ! For an autentification system working between a website and a pgsql database, can I only use Node.js, Express, Passport and the PG module ?

Comment: Yeah you can. I suggested Sequelize so that you can familiarize yourself with ORM.

Comment: Oh ok ! But the simplest and faster solution is without Sequelize ?
ORM is making data from database as Object isn't it ? I'm really a novice so my question may be a little stupid because I absolutely don't see , at this time, how to handle this authentication system... but do you really think I need to "OMRiser" the login data ?